# Remember access to camera settings on http

Tags: google-chrome, browser

My project require access to camera but browser doesn't remember its settings and ask for permission every time. I know browser only remember camera access settings for https website.

My project doesn't require ssl at all and works on localhost only. Is there a way to force browser to remember camera access for http connection .